# Some code to force a user to enter a choice

Tags: c++

I'm quite new to c++ and I need help on some code to force a user to make a choice. The first choice calls back the main function and the second choice calls `return 0`, else the program isn't suppose to `return 0` in the main function on any choice. The choice are `Y` or `y` for yes and `n` or `N` for no, aside these letters the code is not to accept any letter.
I would appreciate it a lot if I receive a help, Thank you.

```
    #include "person. h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std; 

    int main()
    {
person persons; 

persons. getInfo();

persons.showInfo();

cout << "do you want to continue, type Y or y for yes and n or N for no to exit" << endl; 

char choice; 

cin >> choice; 

if (choice == ("Y"||"y"))
{
int main();
}

if (choice == ("N"||"n"))
{
return 0;
}

else
{
 cout << "please make a choice"; cin >> choice; 
 } /* This is where I would like to iterate in other for the     user to make one of the choices provided above */


return 0;
 }
```

Comment: _"Gimme teh codez plz"_ Are you serious? Go to the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to figure out what you can ask here please.

Comment: Help on .. ? Can you show your code so we can help you?

Comment: To force a user simply employ an enforcer.

Answer (score 0):

You could employ something like:

```
if(choice == "Y" || choice == "y")
    int main();
else
    return 0;
```

So they must put Y or y to continue, and then anything else will terminate the program with `return 0;`